# Integral simplification

Tags: calculus

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{-1} e^{ikx} \left( \frac{-A}{-x-1+\sqrt{x^2-1}} \right)dx = \frac{A}{2}\int_1^\infty e^{-ikx} \left( 1 - \sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x-1}} \right)dx.
$$
Hello, thank you very much for this website, I want to know how is it possible to express the integral in the left side as the integral in the right side? I have tried rationalizing the denominator in the left side but nothing happens. (I know that the integral in the right side can be expressed in terms of the modified bessel functions of the second kind of order zero and order one.) However,I don't understand how can the integral be expressed from the left side to the right side

Thank you very much

Comment: It does not answer your question, but maybe you can find [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) guide useful, if you want to learn how to type in MathJax.

Comment: $-x-1=-(x+1)=-(\sqrt{x+1})^2$ so you can factorize the bottom line and go from there.

Comment: Infact, considering the range of integration, better to change variables first so that the integral goes 1 to infinity. Now take out an $\sqrt{x-1}$ factor on the bottom line and use the difference of 2 squares to finish.

Comment: Thank you, I can follow the factorization, but how to change the variables to make the integral between 1 and infinity?

Answer (score 0):

Set $x\equiv-x$ then your integral can be rewritten as
\begin{align}\int^{-1}_{-\infty}e^{ikx}\frac{-A}{-x-1+\sqrt{x^2-1}}\,dx&=-\int^{1}_{\infty}e^{-ikx}\frac{-A}{x-1+\sqrt{x^2-1}}\,dx\\&=\int^{\infty}_{1}e^{-ikx}\frac{-A}{x-1+\sqrt{x^2-1}}\,dx\\
&=\int^{\infty}_{1}e^{-ikx}\frac{-A(x-1-\sqrt{x^2-1})}{(x-1)^2-(x^2-1)}\,dx\\
&=\int^{\infty}_{1}e^{-ikx}\frac{-A(x-1-\sqrt{x^2-1})}{2-2x}\,dx\\
&=\int^{\infty}_{1}e^{-ikx}\frac{A(x-1-\sqrt{x^2-1})}{2(x-1)}\,dx\\
&=\frac{A}{2}\int^{\infty}_{1}e^{-ikx}\frac{(x-1-\sqrt{x^2-1})}{x-1}\\&
=\frac{A}{2}\int^{\infty}_{1}e^{-ikx}(1-\sqrt\frac{x+1}{x-1})\,dx\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much, how you flip the sign in the first step? did you multiply the variable of integration x by a minus sign such that the sign of the limits of integration change?

Comment: @copets: yes basically I made the substitution $x\to-x$ and the sign of the limits of integration change.

Comment: @copets:you're welcome! :)